# E195012: Unable to find repository location but location exists

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm having an issue with SVN that doesn't make sense to me.

I have two branches, say Branch01 and Branch02 existing at the same time. 
Say the locations are 
svn://mysvnserver.com/product/branch01 and svn://mysvnserver.com/product/branch02

Changes are made to Branch01 and now I want Branch02 to look just like Branch01. I've deleted Branch02 in the repository, then I branched Branch01 off to a new Branch02. So the paths haven't really changed.

I have both branches set up on a CruiseControl.NET continuous integration server to automate my builds.

Well since I re-created Branch02, CruiseControl.NET keeps telling me the build failed with the following error:
E195012: Unable to find repository location...

...and goes on to show the URL of the repository that actually exists. I can see it in the repo-browser in TortoiseSVN, I can use the command svn info svn://mysvnserver.com/product/branch02 to see it as well. That location exists. But it doesn't seem to think so.

Any ideas on what's happening here? Why can't it see the newly created branch, and what do I need to do to access it?

CruiseControl.NET has no problems seeing any other branch of any other product I have it building. It just can't see this repository location. I verified its using the correct credentials and using the correct URL to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by performing an SVN Delete on the folder, committing that change, performing a cleanup on that folder, then re-branching Branch02 from Branch01.